# Weird warning in CodeBlocks - C

Tags: c, warnings, codeblocks, compiler-warnings

I got the following warning in CodeBlocks while compiling my program:
"|5|: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'gamma' [enabled by default]|"
I know it means I'm doing something wrong in the declaration of my function, but that's not what I wanna ask.

If I replace "gamma" with "Gamma" wherever it appears in the program, no warning is given back. The program works perfectly in both cases, but I was wondering I anybody could tell me why "gamma" gives problems and "Gamma" doesn't.

### My program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void lee_datos(int *,int *);
double gamma(int);

main()
{
    int x,y,z,opcion=1;
    double a,b,c,Beta;

    while(1)
    {
        lee_datos(&x,&y);

        a=gamma(x);
                    printf("\n");
        b=gamma(y);
                    printf("\n");
        z=x+y;
        c=gamma(z);
                    printf("\n");

        [...]
    }
    printf("\nFin del programa\n");
}

void lee_datos(int *p_x,int *p_y)
{
   [...]
}

double gamma(int n)
{
    int i;
    double factorial=1;

    n=n-1;

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        factorial*=i;
        printf("%lf\n",factorial);
    }
    return(factorial);
}
```

---

Thank you very much in advance!

Eduardo

Comment: I can't come up with a good explanation of the source of `gamma()`, only that it is already defined as `double gamma(double x)` as an existing math function. You should use a different name, using `Gamma` does just that, as capitalization matters in identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gamma` is not a standard C function, there is no function named gamma in the ISO C standard library. But some math library (math.h) has it by default. The prototype is:

```
double gamma(double x);
```

so it conflicts with your own `gamma` function which has `int` parameter.

Since `gamma` is not a standard C function, maybe you can compile with `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic` or `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic` or `gcc -ansi` to make compiler conforms to C standard so the library's gamma function won't be included.

Comment: There is the [`lgamma()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lgamma.html) function defined in POSIX, but that still isn't the `gamma()` function.  `man gamma` on Mac OS X points to `tgamma()` and mentions `gamma()` as a deprecated variant.